# TFS 2010 RTM Sharepoint and Reports server asks passwords

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have clean TFS 2010 setup (Single-Server setup) with Sharepoint and SSRS on it. Everything works great except authentication pop-up box when I'm trying to access reports or project portal with IE. Re-read alot of docs but no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the site is identifying as local intranet - if not add it. Make sure in the - in the custom level for the intranet zone, make sure automatic logon only in intranet zone is checked. 
There are other options that might be appropriate for your environment but that should point you in the right direction